# Closed form solution for a binomial coefficient relation?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, stochastic-processes

In following, $x_{n}$ is a set of given numbers, n = 0, 1, 2, ...,
$y_{n}$ is defined by the following recursive relation of $x_{n}$:

For example:

${\displaystyle {x_{1}=x_{0}y_{1} }}.$

${\displaystyle {x_{2}={\binom {1}{0}}x_{0}y_{2} + {\binom {1}{1}}x_{1}y_{1}  }}.$

${\displaystyle {x_{3}={\binom {2}{0}}x_{0}y_{3} + {\binom {2}{1}}x_{1}y_{2}  + {\binom {2}{2}}x_{2}y_{1}  }}.$

For simplicity, we can assume $x_{0} = 1$.

Q1: Is there an explicit solution of $y_{n}$ in term of $x_{n}$ ?

Q2: I assume that above relation should be well known, is it a name for such relation ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning Q1, under natural general conditions we can express the exponential generating function of $(y_{j+1})_{j=0}^\infty$ in terms of the exponential generating function of $(x_i)_{i=0}^\infty$.

Indeed, let 
$$u_i:=\frac{x_i}{i!},\quad v_i:=\frac{y_{i+1}}{i!}
$$
for $i=0,1,\dots$. Then 
$$(m+1)u_{m+1}=\sum_{i=0}^m u_i v_{m-i} \tag{1}
$$
for $m=0,1,\dots$. So, if e.g. $|v_i|\le C^i$ for some real $C\ge1$ and all $i$, then, by induction, $|u_i|\le C^i$ for all $i$. Hence, we can define the exponential generating functions $U$ and $V$ of $(y_{j+1})_{j=0}^\infty$ and $(x_i)_{i=0}^\infty$ by 
$$U(s):=\sum_{i=0}^\infty u_is^i,\quad V(s):=\sum_{i=0}^\infty v_is^i
$$
for all $s$ close enough to $0$. Then (1) can be rewritten as $U'(s)=U(s)V(s)$, so that 
$$V=U'/U. 
$$

Comment: Thank you.  Binomial coefficient does not appear in above formula (1) ?

Comment: @david : Indeed, the binomial coefficient does not appear in (1), and that is the key. The factorial factors in the binomial coefficient get absorbed into the $u_i$'s and $v_i$'s.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @david : I think (1) rather suggests that this problem has actually not much to do with binomial coefficients.